# Microsoft Access 2010 Date Issue

Tags: ms-access-2010

In access 2010 the #DATE_VALUE# format is not working. We need to typecast the date to INT like Int(#DATE_VALUE#). Is there any alternate way to this ?

Comment: Same format is working fine in Access 2002. But, here without typecasting it is not function-able.

Comment: I have Office 2010, the #DATE_VALUE# is working perfectly: I tried: SELECT MyDate FROM Table1 WHERE MyDate>#1/1/1990#;

Comment: I remember in the older versions #Date_Value# was strictly US format only i.e. MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: JET always uses `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Please explain what exactly you mean by **not working**

Comment: I am getting this error if I don't typecast: ODBC Call Failed....[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character String . (#241)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this error, and came up with:

[Access frontend, SQL backend: Datetime format is changed and VBA-code as Addnew and setting dates are not working](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7305ad70-0084-43ec-8379-532d430da9d4/access-frontend-sql-backend-datetime-format-is-changed-and-vbacode-as-addnew-and-setting-dates?forum=sqlservermigration)

The solution proposed here is to install the SQL Server Native Driver on the local machine, and modifying your ODBC driver to: `DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0`

Check out this post, and see if you are using the appropriate SQL Server Native Driver on your machine and in your ODBC connection string.